# Itext 5 Table rows splitting to new page and repeating

Tags: java, android, itext, pdf-generation

I am using itext 5 legacy for the first time and I am new to app development. 
I am generating a table that keeps splitting the columns into new rows on a  new page and it would repeat the data.

The first Table:
[image: The first Table]
The second table with split columns and repeating data:
[image: The second table with split columns and repeating data]

Third table:
[image: Third table]

The fourth table:
[image: The fourth table]

The fifth Table:
[image: The fifth Table]

The table is required to be one long row.
Please help me rectify this,

Here is the code:

```
    private void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException,IOException {
       // getIntent().setType("application/pdf");
        Toast.makeText(this,"GENERATING PDF ..."+ directory_path,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        File file = new File(directory_path+filename);
        if (!file.exists())
        {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
        ProductCondition prodCond = new ProductCondition(true,"GREEN","BFobrourinbiurfufbjfnbbu");
        ProductOperations prodOper = new ProductOperations(true,true,true,1000,986,500,"OBNobdfiuvdob");
        Product product = new Product("bkbukb","sfdvsf","sdfsdfs","1sfdssV45",prodCond,prodOper);
        technicians.addProduct(product);
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A1.rotate());
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(directory_path+filename));
        document.open();
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(15);
        table.setTotalWidth(5000);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        List<String> listData =new ArrayList<>() ;
        listData = GetTechnicianData(technicians);
        Image image1 = GetImage();
        Image image2 = GetImage();
        table.addCell("Bloop");
        table.addCell("han Solo");
        table.addCell("Hamburger");
        table.addCell("NUmber time");
        table.addCell("boogaloo");
        table.addCell("Boo thang");
        table.addCell("Spanish");
        table.addCell("Inquisition");
        table.addCell("Never ");
        table.addCell("Death");
        table.addCell("Test ");
       // table.addCell("Button");
        table.addCell("Lights");
        table.addCell("Sunshine");
        table.addCell("Comment");
        table.addCell("Images");
        table.setHeaderRows(3);
        table.setFooterRows(1);
        table.getDefaultCell().setBackgroundColor(GrayColor.GRAYWHITE);
        PdfPCell cell;
        Toast.makeText(this,"ADDING PRELIMINARY DATA",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            for (int c = 0; c < 14; c++) {
                cell = new PdfPCell();
                cell.setFixedHeight(50);
                cell.addElement(new Paragraph(listData.get(c)));
                cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                //cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
                table.addCell(cell);
                table.setKeepTogether(true);
            }
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.add(new Chunk(image1,0,0,true));
        p.add(new Chunk(image2,0,0,true));
        cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.addElement(p);
        //cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        table.addCell(cell);
        //document.add(table);
        Toast.makeText(this,"ADDING IMAGES...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          /*  cell = new PdfPCell();
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
            p.add(new Chunk(image1,0,0,true));
            p.add(new Chunk(image1,0,0,true));
            cell.addElement(p);
            table.addCell(cell);*/

       // document.add(table);


        PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfTemplate tableTemplate = canvas.createTemplate(5000, 2600);
        table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, 800, tableTemplate);
        PdfTemplate clip;
        for (int j = 0; j <5000; j += 1000) {
            table.setKeepTogether(true);
            document.newPage();
            for (int i = 2600; i > 0; i -= 1300) {

                clip = canvas.createTemplate(2000, 1300);
                clip.addTemplate(tableTemplate, -j, 1750 - i);
                canvas.addTemplate(clip, 50, 312);
                table.setKeepTogether(true);
                //canvas.addImage(image1);
            }
        }
        // byte [] pdf = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
        Uri filepdf = Uri.fromFile(new File(directory_path+filename));
        UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.child(technicians.getEmailAddress()).child("PDFUpdate").putFile(filepdf);
        Toast.makeText(this,"PDF Generated Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        document.close();

       /* PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
        List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Download a PDF Viewer to see the generated PDF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
*/
    }
    private void createPdfWrapper() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException ,IOException{

        int hasWriteStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (hasWriteStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to Storage",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(CentralHome.this, new String[]{ Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                    return;
                }
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                return;
            }

        } else {
            createPdf();
        }
    }

    private Image GetImage() throws BadElementException,IOException{


            Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
            BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) d);
            Bitmap bmp = bitDw.getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            image.scalePercent(10);
            return image;
            // document.add(image);

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what your expected result is. For example creating a 15-column table with 3 header rows and 1 footer row requires 15*(3+1) = 60 cells for headers and footers alone. You add only 31 cells, though, so you should expect issues...

Comment: Hey thank you for commenting  @mkl, i am completely new to itext and generating pdf's. Its supposed to have only 15 cells per row, but they duplicate and add to the next row on the next page. Look at Table 1 and 2, some cells from table 1 are duplicated to table 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `createPdf` you have a loop that adds sections of the template with the whole table to separate pages:

```java
for (int j = 0; j <5000; j += 1000) {
    table.setKeepTogether(true);
    document.newPage();
    for (int i = 2600; i > 0; i -= 1300) {
        clip = canvas.createTemplate(2000, 1300);
        clip.addTemplate(tableTemplate, -j, 1750 - i);
        canvas.addTemplate(clip, 50, 312);
        table.setKeepTogether(true);
        //canvas.addImage(image1);
    }
}
```

Each section is 2000 units wide (`canvas.createTemplate(2000, 1300)`) but when advancing to the next section you only go right by 1000 units (`j += 1000`). Thus, each new section (except the first one) repeats the last three columns (the second half) of the previous section.

You can prevent these repetitions by going right by 2000 units after each section, i.e. by replacing

```java
for (int j = 0; j <5000; j += 1000)
```

by

```java
for (int j = 0; j <5000; j += 2000)
```

---

As an aside, there are numerous other weirdnesses in your code, e.g.

```java
table.setHeaderRows(3);
table.setFooterRows(1);
```

(here you declare that you have three header rows and one footer row to repeat automatically if the table is added to the `Document` directly and split over multiple pages; as you don't add the table to the `Document` but manually to a template, that functionality is not used which is fortunate as you only create enough cells to fill two rows, not even enough for the declared header rows)

and multiple calls of

```java
table.setKeepTogether(true)
```

*after* already having rendered the table in

```java
table.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, 800, tableTemplate)
```

After rendering the table it is too late to set properties controlling the rendering process...

---

In a comment you said that you only wanted to have a normal 15 column table, not one whose columns are spread across multiple pages. In that case why don't you simply do

```java
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A1.rotate());
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(directory_path+filename));
document.open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(15);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);

... create cells and add them to the table ...

document.add(table);
document.close();
```

All the usage of `PdfContentByte`, `PdfTemplate`, and `writeSelectedRows` is completely unnecessary for your use case.

Comment: Thank you so much @mkl the cells stopped duplicating onto the next row. Is there anyway i could have all the cells on one row? And also for the table to go to the next row immediately after the previous row (like any ordinary table of data )and not to the nextpage? I put the `document.newPage()` in the outer loop, because in the inner loop the cells are generated on top of each other.

Comment: *"Is there anyway i could have all the cells on one row?"* - You mean instead of the one table with 15 columns and 2 rows you want one table with 30 columns and 1 row? Simply instantiate `table` as `new PdfPTable(30)` instead of `new PdfPTable(15)`. *"And also for the able to go to the next row immediately after the previous row and not to the nextpage?"* - What do you mean? The table is drawn in `PdfTemplate tableTemplate` in one piece, then **your own code** cuts this connected table into pieces and spreads them over multiple pages. If you don't want that, why do you do it?

Comment: I need 15 columns in one row. Previously it seemed like 30 because the cells were duplicated. But from the output i get now i get 5 columns in 3 rows. So i wanted to create a dynamic table with x amount of rows of 15 columns each and it must only skip to the next page when it has reached the page boundary. I used the code from one of the itext examples and tried to adapt it to my data, so i didnt really understand some of the functions.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you took a completely inappropriate example to start from. See the edit to my answer for an alternative, simpler approach.